# Как перемещать окно без titleBar'а заполненное до краев webView?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

Одно из окон моего проекта представляет собой нечто похожее на родную имплементацию "картинка в картинке".

[image]

Окошко, разумеется, не движется с места, ибо titleBar у него отсутствует (он скрыт и `window.stylemask` содержит `.fullSizeContentView`) а так же view заполнено до краев webView.

Таким образом, я не могу просто кликнуть на titleBar и потянуть окно куда заблагорассудится. Желаемый результат - окно, которое можно тягать из любой точки на webView.

`isMovableByWindowBackground = true` + subclassing WebView для переопредления `mouseDownCanMoveWindow` на `return true` не сработало

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341278/mousedown-not-firing-in-webview-subclass посмотрите, расписано в чем проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогла [эта ссылка](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/PhotoEditor/Listings/Photo_Editor_WindowDraggableButton_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017384-Photo_Editor_WindowDraggableButton_swift-DontLinkElementID_22). А так же использование WKWebView вместо устаревшего WebView.

Код в классе, наследующемся от WKWebView, выглядит примерно так:

```
override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    let window = self.window!
    let startingPoint = event.locationInWindow
    var shouldCallSuper = false
    window.trackEvents(matching: [.leftMouseDragged, .leftMouseUp],
                       timeout: NSEventDurationForever,
                       mode: .defaultRunLoopMode) { (event, stop) in
        switch event.type {
        case .leftMouseUp:
            shouldCallSuper = true
            NSApp.postEvent(event, atStart: false)
            stop.pointee = true

        case .leftMouseDragged:
            let currentPoint = event.locationInWindow
            if (fabs(currentPoint.x - startingPoint.x) >= 5 || fabs(currentPoint.y - startingPoint.y) >= 5) {
                stop.pointee = true
                window.performDrag(with: event)
            }

        default:
            break
        }
    }

    if (shouldCallSuper) {
        super.mouseDown(with: event)
    }
}
```